# dojo: custom ListItem in EdgeToEdgeStoreList

Tags: javascript, mobile, dojo, store, mixins

I want to use a custom ListItem for an EdgeToEdgeStoreList in dojox/mobile.
From here:

https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/mobile/templating-mobile-widgets.html

I created my template:

```
var template =
    "<div>" +
    "       <div data-dojo-attach-point='labelNode'></div> ${size}" +
    "</div>";

TemplatedListItem = declare(
    [ListItem, TemplatedMixin], {
        label: "My label",
        size: "0",
        templateString: template
    }
);
```

then I set up my store:

```
store = new Memory({data: JSON.parse(json), idProperty: "Desc"});
list = registry.byId("list");
list.setStore(store)
```

but I don't understand how to tell EdgeToEdgeStoreList to use my template:

```
ul#list(data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/EdgeToEdgeStoreList" data-dojo-props="itemMap: {Desc: 'label', Notes: 'size'}, select: 'single'")
```

### Update (working code)

I created a new package, in CustomItem.js:

```
define([
    "dojox/mobile/ListItem",
    "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
    "dojo/_base/declare"
], function (ListItem, TemplatedMixin, declare) {
    var template =
        "<div>" +
        "       <div data-dojo-attach-point='labelNode'></div> ${size}" +
        "</div>";

    TemplatedListItem = declare("CustomItem",
        [ListItem, TemplatedMixin], {
            label: "My label",
            size: "0",
            templateString: template
        }
    );
});
```

then I added it to dojoConfig:

```
dojoConfig = {
    has: {
        "dojo-firebug": true,
        "dojo-debug-messages": true
    },
    packages: [{
        name: "Alert",
        location: "/javascripts",
        main: "alert"
    }, {
        name: "CustomItem",
        location: "/javascripts",
        main: "CustomItem"
    }],
    parseOnLoad: false,
    mblHideAddressBar: true,
    async: true
};
```

required like other packages:

```
require([
    "dojox/mobile/parser",
    "dojox/mobile/compat",
    "dojox/mobile/EdgeToEdgeStoreList",
    "dojox/mobile/SimpleDialog",
    "CustomItem",
    "dojo/domReady!"
], function (parser) {
    parser.parse();
});
```

and set the itemRenderer property:

```
ul#list(data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/EdgeToEdgeStoreList" data-dojo-props="itemRenderer: CustomItem, itemMap: {Desc: 'label', Notes: 'size'}, select: 'single'")
```

but I get this weird error:

> TypeError: registry.byId(...) is undefined

Comment: I need to remove the domReady requirement!